# Manifold with corners

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Iam looking at the following situation of a manifold $Z$ with corners.
More specifically a product of a smooth manifold X with a standard $k$-simplex $\Delta^k$.
I wish to study certain formulas for $X\times \Delta^k$, which hold for manifolds with boundary.
Technically how does one write the above product as a limit of manifolds with boundary (exhausting the simplex from inside). or is there a reference where such constructions have been used before.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Manifolds with corners are treated [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf) and also [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/reflec.pdf).